# Adding object to NSMutableArray in an NSMutableDictionary in another NSDictionary

Tags: ios, nsmutablearray, addition, nsmutabledictionary

So I have a dictionary in a dictionary with arrays. I am trying to add to the arrays that are in the second dictionary.

```
 [mealInfo setObject:[[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init] forKey:@"breakfast"];
 [[mealInfo objectForKey:@"breakfast"] setObject:[[NSMutableArray alloc] init] forKey:@"name"];
    [[mealInfo objectForKey:@"breakfast"] setObject:[[NSMutableArray alloc] init] forKey:@"detail"];
    [[mealInfo objectForKey:@"breakfast"] setObject:[[NSMutableArray alloc] init] forKey:@"ndb"];
    [[mealInfo objectForKey:@"breakfast"] setObject:[[NSMutableArray alloc] init] forKey:@"id"];
    [[mealInfo objectForKey:@"breakfast"] setObject:[[NSMutableArray alloc] init] forKey:@"alias"];
```

The creation seems to be working just the adding multiple elements to the arrays is where I end up with a SIGABRT error

I add like such

```
[[[initMealInfo->mealInfo objectForKey:@"breakfast"] objectForKey:@"name"] addObject:[food_prop objectForKey:@"description"]];
```

I know I am doing something wrong and would like to figure out what any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Try breaking up the line and see which part it fails on

Comment: make sure "[food_prop objectForKey:@"description"]" is not nil

Comment: I bet `[food_prop objectForKey:@"description"]` is `nil`

Comment: Curses @OmarAbdelhafith, you're 29 seconds faster than me!

Comment: @deanWombourne hehe, sorry mate i was here first :P

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly, are you using ARC? Else you have a lot of trouble.

---

You should read up on the Principle of Least Knowledge and the [Law Of Demeter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_Demeter)

Is making the structure like this more intuitive:

```
    NSMutableDictionary *mealInfo = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];

    NSMutableDictionary *breakfast = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
    [breakfast setObject:[[NSMutableArray alloc] init] forKey:@"name"];
    [breakfast setObject:[[NSMutableArray alloc] init] forKey:@"detail"];
    [breakfast setObject:[[NSMutableArray alloc] init] forKey:@"ndb"];
    [breakfast setObject:[[NSMutableArray alloc] init] forKey:@"id"];
    [breakfast setObject:[[NSMutableArray alloc] init] forKey:@"alias"];

    [mealInfo setObject:breakfast forKey:@"breakfast"];
```

Then try breaking it down a bit when you try to enter information and wrap it in a function

```
-(void) addMealName:(NSString*) name forMeal:(NSString*) meal 
{
    NSMutableDictionary *meals = [mealInfo objectForKey:meal];
    NSMutableArray *mealNames = [breakfast objectForKey:@"name"];
    [mealNames addObject:name];
    [meals setObject:breakfastNames forKey:@"name"];
    [mealInfo breakfast forKey:meal];
}
```

And call

```
NSString *newMealName = [food_prop objectForKey:@"description"];
[initMealInfo addMealName:newMealName forMeal:@"breakfast"];
```

Comment: I got mine working but I like your solution. They are all now talking to the correct things but I was missing something that was big, basically I was overriding the array and that was no good. Now I am not and it is working. I am having it complicated like this mostly because it will save a lot of lines of code as well as save a lot of internal function calls which i feel is less efficient compared to using the calls that are built into the system over all. But yours will work and thus I will make it the answer cause it is easier method to follow then mine.

Comment: More efficient isn't always less lines of code. The compiler will often compress all this down for you. Also think about debugging time, you've had to spend extra time asking people to help you fix this which has taken longer than writing out a more broken down solution.

Comment: I know that more compressed is not always more efficient but the dictionary of dictionary of arrays is an object that is local and takes away 30 calls to getters and setters in another NSObject and brings it all locally that is referenced at an O(1) referencing. Also, my referencing since it is avoiding all those function calls it will lead to more efficient assembly language which will result in higher efficiency. Also, pertaining to the debugging I actually fixed it right when i sent this out. I was transferring data structures which is always a big task that leads to over lap and errors.

Comment: If your single function call is O(1), then so is mine since it is just your's broken into it's individual commands. You really don't have to optimise your assembly, if you do, I'd worry more about your program design. I'd worry about how maintainable your code is. 30 well named getters and setters is far more efficient in the time it takes to write code than the problems you will encounter trying to remember the names of your dictionary keys, etc.